# Combining two queries that use the same table and same column

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

So I'm trying to create a query using the same table and column for two different functions. I can create each query separately and it runs smoothly and effectively.

first query :

```
SELECT "y2018-cpsbsng"."fiscal_year" as "FY", 
"y2018-cpsbsn"."county", "y2018-cpstxsc"."child_population" as "Child Population", 
SUM("y2018-cpsbsng"."victims") AS "TOTAL ALLEGED"
FROM "y2018-cpstxsc" INNER JOIN "y2018-cpsbsng" USING ("county", "fiscal_year")
GROUP BY "y2018-cpsbsng"."fiscal_year", "y2018-cpsbsng"."county", "y2018-cpstxsc"."child_population"
ORDER BY "y2018-cpsbsng"."fiscal_year" ASC, "y2018-cpsbsng"."county" ASC
```

Output 1:

`FY     county      Child Population      TOTAL ALLEGED
2008    Anderson    11237                 808
2008    Andrews     3821                  297`

Second Query:

```
SELECT "fiscal_year", "county", "victims" as "Confirmed Victims" 
FROM "y2018-cpsbsng" 
WHERE "victims" in 
(select "victims" FROM "y2018-cpsbsng" 
where "y2018-cpsbsng"."confirmed_victims" = 'Confirmed Victim')
```

Output 2:

```
fiscal_year   county     Confirmed Victims
2008          Anderson   8
2008          Andrews    1
```

However, once I try to combine both queries into one:

```
SELECT "fiscal_year","county", SUM("victims") AS "TOTAL ALLEGED",
victims
FROM "y2018-cpsbsng"
WHERE victims IN
(SELECT "victims"
FROM "y2018-cpsbsng" 
WHERE "y2018-cpsbsng"."confirmed_victims" = 'Confirmed Victim')
GROUP BY "fiscal_year", "county", victims
ORDER BY "fiscal_year" ASC,"county" ASC
```

This happens (final output):

```
fiscal_year  county     TOTAL ALLEGED   victims
2008         Anderson   247             247
2008         Andrews    561             561
```

And if I get rid of the GROUP BY ...."victims" (which I believe is what's causing the duplicate numbers) I will get an error saying { column "y2018-cpsbsng.victims" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...ear", "county", SUM( "victims" ) "TOTAL ALLEGED", "victims" } and any other way that I try to fix it the error says that { More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression }

Can anyone tell me how I can combine these two queries effectively? 
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: please edit you question and add a code and not a picture

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I just finished editing it!

Comment: Any time you see a table with a year and/or a hyphen in its name, alarm bells should start ringing. Seriously consider whether your design is optimal. Oh, and figure outt which RDBMS you're using!

Comment: In Oracle, `victims` and `"victims"` would be two different columns. Is that the case here?

Comment: Yes, they are different columns

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` both queries as table expressions. The `ORDER BY` needs to be extracted an placed at the end.

For example:

```
select
  b."fiscal_year",
  a."county",
  a."TOTAL ALLEGED",
  b."Confirmed Victims" as "Vistims"
from ( -- first query
  SELECT "y2018-cpsbsng"."fiscal_year" as "FY", 
  "y2018-cpsbsn"."county", "y2018-cpstxsc"."child_population" as "Child Population", 
  SUM("y2018-cpsbsng"."victims") AS "TOTAL ALLEGED"
  FROM "y2018-cpstxsc" INNER JOIN "y2018-cpsbsng" USING ("county", "fiscal_year")
  GROUP BY "y2018-cpsbsng"."fiscal_year", "y2018-cpsbsng"."county", "y2018-cpstxsc"."child_population"
) a
join ( -- second query
  SELECT "fiscal_year", "county", "victims" as "Confirmed Victims" 
  FROM "y2018-cpsbsng" 
  WHERE "victims" in 
  (select "victims" FROM "y2018-cpsbsng" 
  where "y2018-cpsbsng"."confirmed_victims" = 'Confirmed Victim')
) b on a."FY" = b."fiscal_year"
ORDER BY a."FY" ASC, a."county" ASC -- now the ordering
```

If you have rows on one query that are not present on the other, and you want them in the resulting query you must use `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: This worked! had to modify it a little but it did the trick! thanks so much! :)